# Advanced Tomato (Shibby) adblock whitelist doesn't work

Tags: router, firmware, tomato

I'm using Advanced Tomato (ver. 3.5-140), which is based on Shibby Tomato, on my Linksys E4200 router. The adblock function works, but the whitelist doesn't. When I add an url to the whitelist and save on the router, it will work for a couple of minutes, meaning I could open links that are in the whitelist. But after a while those links will be blocked again. How can I know if it's Advanced Tomato problem or Shibby Tomato problem? And where do I reach out to to get it fixed?